# Append strings to our hyperlink in jsp

Tags: jsp

Can you give me any simple example?

For example I took an error when I try to add my strings:

```
String id = line.split(" / ")[0];
String ssid = line.split(" / ")[1]; 

table += "<tr><td><a href="person.jsp?id=<%=id%>&ssid=<%=ssid%>">Link</a></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing JSP *scriptlets* in Java code and the `"` after `href=` is closing the string too early. This is incorrect. The basic fix would be:

```
table += "<tr><td><a href=\"person.jsp?id=" + id + "&ssid=" + ssid + "\">Link</a></td></tr>";
```

Note that you would also like to [`URLEncode`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) those parameters to prevent that you end up with a malformed URL.

Better would be to [stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) using Java code and JSP *scriptlets* for presentation. You could use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`<c:url>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/url.html) and [`<c:param>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/param.html) to create links with URL-encoded parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually closing the string, by opening a `href` attribute, to insert a value. Escape ' " ' characters by using an **escape character** ' \ '.

```
table += "<tr><td><a href=\"person.jsp?id=<%=id%>&ssid=<%=ssid%>\">Link</a></td></tr>";
```

[This will work.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Comment: Thx for your response but I think you forget " before \

Comment: @eddie1907 I am glad it helped, and everything is alright - it is compilable this way.